# I can't redirect to another page in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, passport.js, push

I have successfully authenticated the user in MERN using passport.js.
The problem is i want to say that if user already exist then just redirect him in the profile,
so i tested

```
        if (user) {
            (response => {
                this.props.history.push('/profile')
            })
        }
```

But it doesnt redirect to profile with that way.

I have already tried with just console.log("Works")
but as I see only the push function doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Here is full code:

```
const Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const GoogleUser = require('../models/google');


const GoogleAuth = new Strategy ({ passReqToCallback:true, usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'id' }, function(req, email, id,done){ 

    GoogleUser.findOne({ email: req.body.email}).lean().exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err, null);
        }

        if (user) {
            (response => {
                this.props.history.push('/profile')
            })
        }

        else{
            let newUser = new GoogleUser({
                email : req.body.email,
                id : req.body.id,
                name : req.body.name,
                token : req.body.token,
                image : req.body.image
            })

            newUser.save((error, inserted) => {
                if (error) {
                    return done(error, null);
                }

                return done(null, inserted);

            })
        }
    })  

});

module.exports = GoogleAuth;
```

The Authentication:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express.Router();
const passport = require('../passport')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../models/user');
const GoogleUser = require('../models/google');
const Strategy = require('passport-local').Strategy

app.post('/google', (req, res, next) =>{
  passport.authenticate('google', function(error, user, info){
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({

        message: error || 'Something happend',
        error : error.message || "Server error"

      });  
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(error, data){
      if (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({

          message: error || 'Something happend',
          error : error.message || "Server error"

        });  
      }

      return res.json(user);

    })
  })(req, res, next);


})



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you post the react component code also?

Comment: You mean the App.js or My login jsx?

Comment: The file in which you need to check if the user is logged in.

Comment: Done i edit my post

Comment: @AjinKabeer Do you know how to fix it?